# Convert PDF To Image - library or command line - free

Tags: c#, pdf, ghostscript

How can I convert each pages of a PDF's file in C#, using free command line or free library?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting PDF to images?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511665/converting-pdf-to-images)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example commandlines for Ghostscript converting multipage PDF to images (1 image per page):

```
gswin32c ^
  -o gray_page_%03d.png ^
  -sDEVICE=pnggray ^
   input.pdf
```

.

```
gswin32c ^
  -o page_%03d.png ^
  -sDEVICE=png256 ^
   input.pdf
```

.

```
gswin32c ^
  -o page_with_alphachannel_%03d.png ^
  -sDEVICE=pngalpha ^
   input.pdf
```

.

```
gswin32c ^
  -o cmyk_page_%03d.jpeg ^
  -sDEVICE=jpegcmyk ^
  -dJPEGQ=80 ^
   input.pdf
```

.

```
gswin32c ^
  -o rgb_page_%03d.jpeg ^
  -sDEVICE=jpeg ^
  -dJPEGQ=100 ^
   input.pdf
```

.

```
gswin32c ^
  -o tiffg4_page_%03d.tiff ^
  -sDEVICE=tiffg4 ^
   input.pdf
```

.

```
gswin32c ^
  -o tiffg32nc_page_%03d.tiff ^
  -sDEVICE=tiff32nc ^
  -sCompression=lzw ^
   input.pdf
```

...and many more are possible....

If you need to control resolutions and page sizes (and not rely on Ghostscript's defaults) add these parameters:

```
-r600x600
```

gives you a horizontal and vertical resolution of 600 dpi.

```
-g5950x8420
```

applies a widths of 5950 "devicepoints" and a height of 8420 "devicepoints". Depending on the resolution used at the same time, the devicepoints will end up on paper in different sizes. In case of a resolution `-r720x720` above example of `-g5950x8420` will become the same as media size of `DIN A4 ISO` (which is in PostScript points `595` by `842`.

Comment: I'm newbie to Ghostscript, is it free for commercial apps? This link has many terms and I feel most of them conclude its not free for commercial apps - http://www.artifex.com/page/licensing-information.html
 Any idea ?

Comment: @HemantTank If the following page (from 2014) is to be believed, the answer is *no*; the author claims $8000 per quarter plus a $5000 set-up fee: http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-much-does-it-cost-to-distribute-ghostscript-commercially/

Answer (score 3):

[ImageMagick.NET](http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/), a .NET wrapper for the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) libraries, is your friend.

ImageMagick offers a variety of image manipulation and [conversion tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php). For converting PDF documents, it is using GhostScript under the hood.

Comment: +1 for mentioning [GhostScript](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/). If command line conversion is all you need you can probably use it directly.